# Migration chart.js with zoom plugin and moment adapter

Tags: chart.js, migration, momentjs, compatibility

I managed to draw several charts with chart.js 3.9.1. I'm trying to migrate to the 4.x.x version, but encounter the following issues:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'helpers')` for chartjs-plugin-zoom

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_adapters')` for chartjs-adapter-moment

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.1/chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-adapter-moment/1.0.1/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js"></script>
```

I believe the first issue car be resolved by adding `type="module"`, but generate the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Based on the integration documentation https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#integrations, both libraries are compatible with chart.js 4.x.x.

Does anyone have an idea about what cause the issue?

Answer (score 7):

As described in the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.1.1/migration/v4-migration.html#specific-changes) you need to use the UMD bundle:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It perfectly works now, but still need to figure out what an UMD bundle is...